# Spooky QTcpSocket behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I have been having nightmares while debugging the next few lines of code, there must be something hidden beyond what I am seeing.

Here's a connection between a client and a server

```cpp
QByteArray Client::request(QByteArray cmd)
{
    //DEBUG << "Command: " << cmd.toStdString().c_str();
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(hostAddress, port, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if (socket->waitForConnected(TIMEOUT))
    {
        socket->write(cmd);
        DEBUG << "Size of bytes written :" << sizeof (cmd);
    }
    else DEBUG << "Couldn't connect to socket";
    if (socket->waitForBytesWritten(TIMEOUT)) DEBUG << "Command sent";
    else DEBUG << "Couldn't write to socket";
    if (socket->waitForReadyRead(TIMEOUT))
    {
        QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
        socket->close();
        return data;
    }
    else DEBUG << "No reply from Server";
    return QByteArray();
}
```

That's basically it for the client, for the server, here are the snippets that matter.

```cpp
class ConnectionHandler : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit ConnectionHandler(QObject *parent = 0);
    void write(QByteArray);

protected:
    void ConnectionHandler::incomingConnection(qintptr descriptor)
{
    DEBUG << "ConnectionHandler:" << "Incoming Connection :" << descriptor;
    ConnectionThread *thread = new ConnectionThread(this, descriptor);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &ConnectionThread::signalIncomingMessage, this, &ConnectionHandler::slotIncomingMessage);
    connect(this, &ConnectionHandler::signalOutgoingMessage, thread, &ConnectionThread::slotOutgoingMessage);
    thread->start();
}

public slots:
    void slotIncomingMessage(QByteArray);
    void slotListen(bool checked){
    if (checked)
    {
        if (!this->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, PORT_NUMBER)) {
            DEBUG << "ConnectionHandler:" << "Could not start the server!";
        } else {
            DEBUG << "ConnectionHandler:" << "Listening...";
        }
    } else {
        this->close();
        DEBUG << "ConnectionHandler:" << "Connection Closed!";
    }
}

signals:
    void signalOutgoingMessage(QByteArray);
};
```

```cpp
class ConnectionThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ConnectionThread(QObject* parent = 0, qintptr descriptor = -1){
    if (descriptor != -1)
    {
        socket = new QTcpSocket();

        DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Connecting to socket number" << descriptor;
        if (!socket->setSocketDescriptor(descriptor))
        {
            DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Connection failed.";
            DEBUG << socket->errorString();
        }
        else
        {
            DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Connected Successfully.";
            connect(socket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, this, &ConnectionThread::slotSocketDisconnected);
        }
    }
    else {
        DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Please provide a descriptor for the connection thread";
    }
}
    void run() override{
    if (socket->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Socket is not connected!";
        DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Closing Thread!";
        emit signalThreadError(socket->errorString());
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Socket is Connected.";
        connect(socket, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &ConnectionThread::slotThreadReadyRead, Qt::DirectConnection);
        exec();
    }
}

signals:
    void signalThreadError(QString);
    void signalIncomingMessage(QByteArray);

public slots:
    void slotThreadReadyRead(){
    QByteArray msg = socket->readAll();

    if (!msg.isEmpty()) {
        emit signalIncomingMessage(msg);
    }

    DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Data in:" << msg;
}
    void slotSocketDisconnected();
    void slotOutgoingMessage(QByteArray msg)
{
    if (socket != nullptr) {
        socket->write(msg);
        if (socket->waitForBytesWritten(TIMEOUT)) {
            DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Outgoing Message: " << msg;
        } else {
            DEBUG << "ConnectionThread: Outgoing Message Timeout";
        }
    }
}

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket = nullptr;
};
```

What happens basically, is it sometimes receives the incoming command from the client, and most of the time it doesn't, not only that, it actually receives some commands and ignores some different ones.

Here's a spookier behavior, notice the line `//DEBUG << "Command: " << cmd.toStdString().c_str();` in the `Client::request()`, when this line is commented out, the server actually receives some commands, when it's not, server is deaf.

here's an output when the line was commented out:

```
Size of bytes written : 8
Command sent
target num = 4  (a reply was received)
Size of bytes written : 8
Command sent
No reply from Server
```

Here's another output when the mentioned line isn't commented out:

```
Command:  NUMB

Size of bytes written : 8
Command sent
No reply from Server
target num = 0
Command:  TRAN

Size of bytes written : 8
Command sent
No reply from Server
```

**Update**
Solving the race that happens between socket writing at the client and thread opening did it for me, thread using was unnecessary in my case here so I just dropped it. Answered by @Botje

Comment: The naming suggests you're using threads in the server code which can complicate things no end.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: that's an odd thread on server side, does it receive socket from another thread?  QObjects are thread-aware. ANd actually the way how connection is formed and how signals are connected does matter . A Lot of wrongs may happen there, some UBs even. Also Qt got things lie QTcpServer and usage of run()  override is considered an outdated approach to use of Qthread

Comment: There is at least one race condition: the thread getting started vs your socket receiving data, thus triggering its readyRead signal. Please show the rest of your code!

Comment: Unrelated: `sizeof cmd` will always be 8. Did you mean `cmd.size()`?

Comment: @G.M. Just did, Client is nothing more than its request()

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I noticed that's it's not the best way to use QThread yes, do you think it may have an underlying hand in what's happening here?

Comment: @Botje yes this may be it, let me test it real quick

Comment: @Botje thanks for the cmd.size() hint

Comment: Also note that `Client::request` blocks whatever thread it is running on. If that is your main thread, it also blocks the `ConnectionThread`'s socket, as that is running on whatever thread created the `ConnectionThread`.

Comment: You create `QTcpSocket` in ctor of thread, ctor of thread got context of thread it is executed from (unless it was moved after  `start()`), i.e. where `QThread` was created. I usually did everything from `run()`. signal - slot connection acts accordingly. But it might be desirable, because slots of thread are processed only while its `exec()`  - event loop - is executed, and not every Qthread override uses that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a race condition:

1. (main thread) ConnectionHandler::incomingConnection creates a new ConnectionThread
2. (main thread) ConnectionThread constructor creates a socket, which is also owned by the main thread
3. (main thread) returns to event loop, polling for incoming data on the socket
4. (ConnectionThread) the run method connects a slot to the readyRead signal

If data arrives in the window between 2 and 4, the readyRead signal would not have picked it up.
There are several possible solutions, but the simplest is probably to either move the socket to the ConnectionThread after construction, or delay its construction until the ConnectionThread::run method.